# Xcode enforcing App extension API only, but I'm not writing an extension or using extension features

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been working on an app since iOS 7, and updated it from 7->8 without a problem, now I'm going to 9 and Xcode is telling me I'm using methods not allowed in an app extension but I'm not writing something constricted to an app extension api.

`'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.`

I've had the app running on simulator and device for iOS 9.  This just randomly happened the other day.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any app extensions, just uncheck "Allow app extension API only" box under *Deployment Info* in the *General* tab of the project settings for your target.

It's odd that it got checked in the first place though. I wonder what happened.

Comment: It was under Build Settings for my target.  I didn't have it for the project build settings, but it was enabled for the target.  No idea why, though.  Thank you!